# How to delete values from first table by using name of the second sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `groups`

```
group_id | name_group
1          ISI
2          IZI
```

And a table `students`

```
id | first_name | last_name | group_id
6    Bob          Surname1    1
17   John         Surname2    2
```

How can I delete all information from `student` table by using `groups.name`?

i.e. I need query which select all students with the same `group_id` which is equivalent to name.

```
group_id 1 = 'ISI'
group_id 2 = 'IZI'
```

And a query must delete exactly by name.

Comment: Create a join based on group_id and include a where group_name like "xyz" in your delete statement.

Comment: Look at the examples here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html#idm46428675201360

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query

```
Delete from Students where group_id=(Select group_id from groups where name_group='ISI');
```

This all the records with the `group_id` of `1` (via `group_name='ISi'`).

Comment: But returns the subquery in the expression returned more than one line

Comment: So does it answer your question or not? If it doesn't, don't mark that it does.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways. A simple one, could be selecting the Id of the group and deleting from there. Example:

```
DECLARE
@name as nvarchar(20) = 'myName'

-- we display the data just for check
SELECT s.*, g.group_id
FROM students s ON g.group_id = s.group_id
WHERE g.name_group = @name

--we look the group id and delete the matches with students
DELETE
FROM students
WHERE group_id in (SELECT group_id FROM groups WHERE name_group = @name)
```

PD: This basic approach could work on both: MySQL and MSSQL.

Comment: What about Postgres?

Comment: The same approach, just changing few words like the [Declaration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-declarations.html) part and if using Joins, could use the [USING](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-delete.html) keyword.

Comment: If you want answers for a particular DBMS , then tag your question for that DBMS only. Otherwise, people will guess, and that's pretty pointless.